# Does a gyroscope require calibration? (MPU 6050)

Tags: calibration, gyroscope

If it does, what is the method that I need to follow? Any suggestions?

Edit:
Are these the offsets?
[image]

Comment: What does the datasheet say? If calibration is needed does not only depend on the device but also what your usage requires. If you just want up/down/left/right information, maybe without calibration the device is accurate enough. If you want more precise data (up while accelerating with x.xx m/s^2) then maybe you need calibration. Or maybe the device calibrates itself. Read the datasheet and you'll know.

Comment: Ya according to the datasheet, it says that they have reduced the need for user to do calibration. But is that enough? Should I still calibrate it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the gyro itself has no problem being uncalibrated. Your project using it might have a problem though.

Comment: I am using it to detect fall.

Comment: Read this and you may be able to ask a more specific question. What is it specifically about the gyro you want to calibrate? Gyros have a lot of parameters that can be calibrated. Some simple, most are difficult. : https://www.vectornav.com/support/library/calibration

Comment: What i am trying to calibrate is the Gyro bias/ offset.

Comment: So why can't you just zero it while its sitting there not turning? Why would you NOT do that when it's so simple? It's the only gyro parameter you can do that with without requiring crazy equipment.

Comment: Are there any formulas to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is always recommended to calibrate the MPU6050 or any other sensor before it is used for the first time as it might not have zero error. All you have to do is, place the sensor in a flat and level position and take the average of the few hundred readings. The gyro should ideally give 0 for all axes. There are many Arduino sketches available to measure the offset and use those as a reference.

https://github.com/kkpoon/CalibrateMPU6050

Comment: "Ideally" it would read the rotation of the earth, but practically this is correct.

Comment: Guys are there any manual way to do it? Because i know we can find out the offset for accelerometer by using formulas.